# What will be the size of this integral domain?

Tags: finite-fields

Let $(R,+,*)$ be an integral domain such that $a*a =a$ for all $a\in R$. What will be the size of $|R|$?

My attempt :
$|R| = 1$, as $a*a=a$ by cancellation law $a = e$ which means $|R|=1$

Comment: (1) In an integral domain the cancellation need only hold for nonzero elements. (2) In the ring with one element, by definition that element is zero, and usually the zero ring is by definition excluded from being an integral domain.

Comment: Is my proof correct?

Comment: No. It is not correct. As Travis explained cancellation does not work when $a=0$.